# Unable to copy file contents using centos Script with cronjob on CentOS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I am trying to copy a file from one folder to another folder on same system in CensOS with a pre-defined schedule set in cronjob. But system is not copying the file.

CentOS version detail in use is shown below.

```
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
```

I have created a shell script in "scripts" folder under my home folder.
This folder is added in the PATH environment variable.
Here are the bash_profile contents.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export CATALINA_HOME=/var/lib/apache-tomcat
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/bin:~/scripts:$PATH
```

Here are the contents of the shell script file in `~/scripts/archivelog.sh`

```
#Script to archive jboss server logs after every 4 hours.
FILE_NAME=server$(date +%y-%m-%d_%H.%M)_log.zip
cd ~/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/
zip $FILE_NAME server.log
echo "" > server.log
echo "LOG Compressed"
cp $FILE_NAME ~/logs/archives/
```

I have set permissions `-rwxrwx---` with `chmod 770 ~/scripts/archivelog.sh`
The script is set as cron job, which runs after every 2 hours, from Monday - Saturday and from 8 AM to 11 PM.

```
0 8-11/2 * * 1-6 ~/scripts/archivelog.sh
```

I have checked the result after ever 2 hours and even I have also checked the script by running it manually, but no file is copied.
Upon investigation I checked that system is copying the file, but naming the file as ?.

With further changes in the script I saw that, if I use

```
cp $FILE_NAME ~/logs/archives/
```

Then it copies the file as `~/logs/archives/?`

if I use

```
cp $FILE_NAME ~/logs/archives
```

Then it copies the file as `~/logs/archives?`

and if I use

```
cp $FILE_NAME ~/logs/archives/$FILE_NAME
```

Then it copies the file as `~/logs/archives/$FILE_NAME?`

Please help me in this regard, same script is running on development servers, but is not running on PRODUCTION Server.

Comment: Sounds like your script has DOS line endings.  This is an extremely common FAQ.  The standard advice is to not edit your files on Windows; if it cannot be avoided, use an editor which allows you to specify the line termination when saving, or run `dos2unix` or similar on the file after copying it to the destination.

Comment: Your script doesn't seem to have a shebang line, so I am surprised you get it to work.  Cron jobs will be run with `sh` unless explicitly marked to be sent to a different interpreter, so bashisms like `~` (pro the portable `$HOME`) are not recommended.  Also, the cron job will not be reading your `.bash_profile`, so what you have there is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

One thing regarding the cronjob schedule, as you said you wanted to run it between 8 AM to 11 PM, but the current setting shows that it will run between 8 AM to 11 PM. You should change the setting to 8-23, time values in linux cron jobs are in 24 hours format. 
Use the settings below. Also instead of `~` use absolute path in cronjob.

```
0 8-23/2 * * 1-6 [PATH]/scripts/archivelog.sh
```

Regarding, file copy issue, I am suspecting that you have prepared the script in windows environment and then transferred the file to linux, thats why there are line ending control/special characters in the script file.
You can see the control characters with `cat -A` command. e.g

```
cat -A ~/scripts/archivelog.sh
```

It would be showing output like this:

```
FILE_NAME=server$(date +%y-%m-%d_%H.%M)_log.zip^M$
cd ~/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/^M$
zip $FILE_NAME server.log^M$
echo "" > server.log^M$
echo "LOG Compressed"^M$
cp $FILE_NAME ~/logs/archives/^M$
```

If you open that file in windows in any windows editor, e.g Notepad++ and turn show all characters, it will show line endings with **CRLF**.

Hopefully this is your case, which I have explained above. In this case you need to remove `\r` characters from your shell script file.
You may use below command to remove these characters from the file.

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' ~/scripts/archivelog.sh
```

if you will see file contents, showing all characters, with below command.

```
cat -A ~/scripts/archivelog.sh
```

It should show contents like below.

```
FILE_NAME=server$(date +%y-%m-%d_%H.%M)_log.zip$
cd ~/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/$
zip $FILE_NAME server.log$
echo "" > server.log$
echo "LOG Compressed"$
cp $FILE_NAME ~/logs/archives/$
```

After executing sed command mentioned, hopefully your script will work well.
Let me know if it is still not working.